# Bubble sort algorithm issue when the size of array is seven

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, bubble-sort

```
public class BubbleSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr1 = {2, 34, 65, 65, 10, 32, 45};
      int[] arr2 = {2, 65, 65, 10, 32, 45};
      int[] arr3 = {2, 34, 65, 65, 32, 45};
      int[] arr4 = {2, 12, 15, 34, 65, 65, 32, 45};
      int[] arr5 = {2, 34, 65, 65, 20, 32, 45};
      bubbleSort(arr1, 1);
      bubbleSort(arr2, 2);
      bubbleSort(arr3, 3);
      bubbleSort(arr4, 4);
      bubbleSort(arr5, 5);
   }

   public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr, int id) {
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
               int tmp = arr[j + 1];
               arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
               arr[j] = tmp;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("This is Arr " + id + " " + arr[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

I am having an issue with my bubble sort implementation in java where I am sorting in ascending mode but as you can see when you run `bubbleSort(arr1)` and `bubbleSort(arr5)` it is returning weird values and it's not the result I'm expecting. What seems to be the problem with this?

**Results**

[arr1 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcH6J.png)
[arr5 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SESR6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is correct, but your print is wrong, you ordered your arr5 you should print him after all iterations, your println is inside one of the for while it still ordering.

Here's a print that I put println outside of your function.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO3QR.png)

It's not correct formated but its what I could make Right now

```
public class BubbleSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr5 = {2, 34, 65, 65, 20, 32, 45};
      bubbleSort(arr5, 5);
      
    int n = arr5.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        System.out.print(arr5[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
   }

   public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr, int id) {
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
               int tmp = arr[j + 1];
               arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
               arr[j] = tmp;
            }
         }
         
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to think how BubbleSort really works.
You are checking in your `if` condition if the current element at position `j` is greater than the element at position `j+1`. If that condition isn't met the elements don't swap.

Your condition makes sure, that after each `i`th iteration the biggest element is at the end of your array.

As you go along and check in each iteration the `i`th element of your array you may encounter, what you consider *weird* values. Looking at your first array. These are the steps in each iteration:

```java
arr = {2, 34, 65, 65, 10, 32, 45};

// arr                               i
// {2, 34, 65, 10, 32, 45, 65};  arr[0] = 2
// {2, 34, 10, 32, 45, 65, 65};  arr[1] = 34
// {2, 10, 32, 34, 45, 65, 65};  arr[2] = 32
// {2, 10, 32, 34, 45, 65, 65};  arr[3] = 34
// {2, 10, 32, 34, 45, 65, 65};  arr[4] = 45
// {2, 10, 32, 34, 45, 65, 65};  arr[5] = 65
// {2, 10, 32, 34, 45, 65, 65};  arr[6] = 65
```

The reason why at `i=1` the element of `arr` is `34` is because when checked you compared `34 > 65` which is False, thus `34` stayed at position `1`.